# handsontable doesn't appear before click or some other operation

Tags: knockout.js, handsontable

I am having knockout binding with handsontable, I just wanted to try Handsontable to replace existing grid in our application, but it has very strange behaviour.

I am using this knockout binding: https://github.com/CalvinSlusarski/Knockout-handsontable
and my model has the same data as in this example.

I am not going to post any code, because I'm unable to reproduce a problem in fiddler. I have complicated workflow when handsontable opens in modal window after pressing some buttons and loading data. Before data are loaded wrapper of handsontable is hidden and binding also doesn't happen.

The problem is that Handsontable doesn't appear until user clicks somewhere on the modal or do something else (for example, pressing F12 to show debug window also shows Handsontable).

Has anybody seen such a behaviour?

Comment: I'm working on the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
ht.view.wt.draw(true);
```

where ht is my instance of handsontable get by handsontable('getInstance');

I use backbone, so I call it when populating the view element.

Also see my pr:

https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/pull/1340

Comment: For simplicity I added this.wt.draw(true); instead of this.wt.draw(!this.instance.forceFullRender).

Comment: I have found out that there are also problems with copy/paste from excel. Values are pasted, but not seen. If you click into cell, then you can see those values.